# Java spring mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring

I have one exception, which is I have no mapping on my table. I have this Exeption

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: org.openmrs.module.queue.model.Queue.queue_clinic in org.openmrs.module.queue.model.QueueClinic.queue
```

I have a table called `queue` with a foreign key called `queue_clinic_id` and another table called `queue_clinic`with a primary key `queue_clinic_id`

Queue entity is here:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "queue")
public class Queue extends BaseChangeableOpenmrsMetadata {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "queue_id")
    private Integer queueId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", nullable = false)
    private Location location;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service", referencedColumnName = "concept_id", nullable = false)
    private Concept service;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "queue_clinic_id", nullable = true)
    public QueueClinic queueClinic;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Where(clause = "voided = 0 and (started_at <= current_timestamp() and ended_at is null)")
    private List<QueueEntry> queueEntries;
    
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return getQueueId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.setQueueId(id);
    }
}
```

And queue clinic entity is here :

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "queue_clinic")
public class QueueClinic extends BaseChangeableOpenmrsMetadata {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "queue_clinic_id")
    private Integer queueClinicId;
    
    @Override
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queue_clinic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Where(clause = "voided = 0 and (started_at <= current_timestamp() and ended_at is null)")
    private List<Queue> queue;
    
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return getQueueClinicId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.setQueueClinicId(id);
    }
}
```

What im i doing wrong? Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: mapedBy uses the name of the variable or class you give in springboot not the name you give to the db colum or table

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference the property fro the `Queue`class

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queueClinic", ...
```